# How to stretch a content on Pivot.RightHeader horizontal?

Tags: xaml, winui-3

Blend reveals `Pivot`'s template and the `ContentPresenter` found beneath but where can I find the default `RightHeaderTemplate` ? I wish to stretch a `RelativePanel` onto the entire right header area.

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="RightHeaderPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding RightHeaderTemplate}" Grid.Column="2" Content="{TemplateBinding RightHeader}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

For example the `TabView.TabStripFooter` can offer this by default.

Tried this for size but to no avail:

```
<Pivot x:Name="MyPivotTable" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.MyItems}" SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.ActiveDocument, Mode=OneWay}">
    <Pivot.RightHeader>
        <RelativePanel Width="{Binding ElementName=MyPivotTable, Path=RightHeader.ActualWidth}">
```

Control is being aligned to the most right:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the default styles, templates in the **generic.xaml**. AFAIK, you should be able to find the **generic.xaml** here:

C:\Users\???.nuget\packages\microsoft.windowsappsdk\1.1.5\lib\net5.0-windows10.0.17763.0\Microsoft.WinUI\Themes\generic.xaml

**UPDATE**

You can stretch the **RightHeader** area by changing the `ColumnDefinitions`. Since the **RightHeaderPresenter** is assigned to `Grid.Column="2"`, this should work:

```xml
<PivotPanel
    x:Name="Panel"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid x:Name="PivotLayoutElement">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <!--
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            -->
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

...

</PivotPanel>
```

Comment: Yes the ```ContentPresenter``` above snatched from the Generic.xaml and it is stretched on both direction but it still results in my control being aligned at most right on the ```RightHeader```.

Comment: Sorry. I thought you wanted to know where you can find the default templates. Can you be more specific about what you want to modify the right header?

Comment: I intend to stretch the relative panel above so that it occupies the entire right header area. Currently the panel's width == cruise button's width and it is aligned to the most right position.

Comment: It has positioned now onto the center of ```RightHeader```.

Comment: I guess you are still using the ``RelativePanel``. Can you try adding ``HorizontalAlignment="Left"`` in the control inside the ``RelativePanel``? If you remove the ``RelativePanel`` and put a ``Button`` directly as a ``RightHeader``, it should be align to the left.

Comment: None of these changes have altered the previous state. ```Button``` is at the center of ```RightHeader```.

Comment: So it was "Auto * Auto" and "Auto Auto *" yields the result. Thanks.